# Is there any incompatibility with PHP 7?

Tags: 7

How well does Drupal 7.56 run on PHP 7?

I've done some testing locally using Drupal 7.52 PHP 7.0.10 and haven't noticed problems. [The system requirements page on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/php) says it works, but there is also a [long discussion about a patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2656548).

Comment: Core works fine with 7.1 in my experience.. Many contrib modules don't work, haven't been updated yet, or produce warnings/notices. Basically YMMV

Comment: Works fine here. Used the official [Drupal Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/drupal/) (which uses PHP 7) and that works fine. Mounted an old project onto it, gave a few warnings, nothing fatal.

Comment: I've been using Drupal 7 on PHP 7 for close to a year now, with almost no problems, and generally a significant performance enhancement. The occasional module throws up a warning, but I've only run into a few that do so.